# Customization for autogenrated index view not working

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, customization

I am using `MVC 4.0` and `entity-framework 5` to generate `model`.

I m trying to understand concept of customization, i followed same steps given in tutorials site like  [this](http://dotnet-munesh.blogspot.in/2015/06/customizing-autogenerated-view-in.html)  and [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/customizing-autogenerated-view-in-entityframework-in-Asp-Net/)

only difference is I am adding this customization class code in different sub folder because when directly try to add this in **model folder** it shows error **employee** class already created in this ( autogenrated by entity framwork)

[image]

> Auto generated code By Entity Framework

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//    This code was generated from a template.
//
//    Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//    Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace CustomizationConceptUmang.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class employee
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
    }
}
```

> Code for customization

```
namespace CustomizationConceptUmang.Models.ViewModel
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(employeeMetaData))]
    public partial class employee
    {
    }
    public class employeeMetaData
    {
        [Display(Name="Employee Name")]
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

> View

```
<th>
     @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.name)
</th>
```

Still it showing **name** instead of  **Employee Name**

please suggest me how to resolve this Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The partials are in different namespaces, so they're two separate classes and the metadata is not applied to the `employee` entity.

Match up the namespace to combine multiple partial classes into one.

Anyway don't use Entity Framework models as viewmodels. Create a separate class with annotations for a viewmodel, and map to and from your entity. You'll thank me later.

Comment: Remove the `.ViewModel` from the namespace of the viewmodel. More detail on [MSDN: Partial Classes and Methods (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx).